# I am facing issue with push notification , iOS devices are receiving duplicate notifications . What might be the issue?

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, backend, amazon-sns

I am working with push notification in iOS . Done with all the prerequisites . While testing the application i found out that iOS devices are receiving the notification multiple times , for eg : If i send "Hi" text to people in my network , they are receiving the notification with "Hi" text up to 10 times. We are using AWS SNS as mediator for delivery .

Comment: Hard to imagine the problem is with APNS. There shouldn't be much to debug here. At the very least there is the original function call to send the message (to AWS) and the call by AWS to invoke APNS. It's possible there is an unresolved promise and the AWS invocation is never formally terminated. Make certain you are explicitly terminating the server call that invokes APNS. There could also be a configuration setting that retries the function up to 10 times because it suspects there is a failure since it's never terminated. 10 is such a suspiciously non-random number that I'd look there first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.